# Run Process issue in automated test - Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a problem with ssh tunneling in Robot Framework test. I set variable ${command} with sshpass command. After that I tried to Run this command in environment via Run Process or Run or Start Process.

```
${command}    Set Variable    sshpass -p password ssh -q -L 1234:192.168.253.18:22 192.168.255.1 -N &
${process}    Run Process    ${command}    cwd=${CURDIR}    shell=True    on_timeout=continue    timeout=5
#${process}    Start Process    ${command}    cwd=${CURDIR}    shell=True    stderr=${CURDIR}/stderr.txt    stdout=${CURDIR}/stdout.txt
#${process}    Run    ${command}
```

If I run this command manualy everything is ok - ssh tunnel is created, process is running.

```
abc@abc:~/robot/EDA$ sshpass -p password ssh -q -L 1234:192.168.253.18:22 192.168.255.1 -N &
[1] 23634
abc@abc:~/robot/EDA$
```

If I run this via Run keyword test is waiting for process complete but it waiting till infinity.

```
20180525 21:46:35.752 - INFO - Starting process: 
sshpass -p password ssh -q -L 1234:192.168.253.18:22 192.168.255.1 -N & 
20180525 21:46:35.752 - DEBUG - Process configuration: 
cwd:     /home/robot/EDA/resources 
shell:   True 
stdout:  PIPE 
stderr:  PIPE 
alias:   None 
env:     None 
20180525 21:46:35.762 - INFO - Waiting for process to complete.
```

If I run this via Start Process:

```
20180525 21:56:01.792 - INFO - +---- START KW: Process.Start Process [ ${command} | cwd=/home/robot/EDA/resources/ | shell=True | stderr=/home/robot/EDA/resources/stderr.txt | stdout=/home/robot/EDA/resources//stdout.txt ]
20180525 21:56:01.793 - INFO - Starting process:
sshpass -p password ssh -q -L 1234:192.168.253.18:22 192.168.255.1 -N &
20180525 21:56:01.793 - DEBUG - Process configuration:
cwd:     /home/robot/EDA/resources/
shell:   True
stdout:  /home/robot/EDA/resources/stdout.txt
stderr:  /home/robot/EDA/resources/stderr.txt
alias:   None
env:     None
20180525 21:56:01.801 - INFO - ${process} = 1
20180525 21:56:01.801 - INFO - +---- END KW: Process.Start Process (9)
20180525 21:56:01.802 - INFO - +--- END KW: EDA.Create Ssh Tunnel (12)
```

stdout.txt and stderr.txt are empty. Process wasn't create.

If I run this command via Run:

```
20180525 22:02:12.226 - INFO - +---- START KW: OperatingSystem.Run [ ${command} ]
20180525 22:02:12.230 - INFO - Running command 'sshpass -p password ssh -q -L 1234:192.168.253.18:22 192.168.255.1 -N  2>&1 &'.
```

and also test is waiting till infinity also.

Someone could help me with this issue?

Comment: The same situation if this command is in a *.sh or *.py file.

Comment: Can you add the information in this comment to the relevant part of the question so that all the information is in 1 place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with robot framework. It is possible to bypass the problem by using a [custom python library](https://robocorp.com/docs/development-guide/robot-framework/how-to-use-custom-python-libraries-in-your-robots).

You need to use the [subprocess library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

```
import subprocess, sys

def exec_ps1_script():
      proc = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\helloworld.ps1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      output, err = proc.communicate()
      rc = proc.returncode
      return rc
```

Then call it in robot framework

```
*** Test Case ***
Run PS1 Code
     [Documentation] Run a PS1 Code in RF
     ${rc}  Exec PS1 Script
     Log  ${rc}
```